# App don't work (black screen) on real iOS device, but works perfectly in iOS emulator

Tags: flutter, dart

I wonder what could cause this issue?

My app works perfectly on iOS simulator, but when installing the app on a real iOS device, it launches with black screen and gets stuck with that. I tried with following commands:

*Flutter clean
*Flutter upgrade
*Flutter doctor

Doctor shows nothing wrong, all works.

Where should I begin debugging?

Comment: Got the same issue, everything works on Android and iOS simulators. Running on a physical device (tried on 5S, 6, 6S) opens the splash screen and after that stays black. I've added some logging when the first screen loads and the logs come through.

Comment: @Kilian Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Yep, for me updating flutter, fixed the issue. Felt pretty stupid after that. So I am afraid I can't help you any further.